# PHPMailer form not erroring or sending

Tags: php, phpmailer

Getting no errors in error_log or on page. Error log definitely working as if I change
`require 'PHPMailer.php';` to `require 'PHPFailer.php';` I get `PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed`

display_errors set to true

error_reporting set to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`

PHPMailer 6.1.7 - PHP 7.2

Both PHPMailer.php and Exception.php are in the root directory. Have commented out the redirects as I just get sent to /php/form_error.php.

Any ideas would be much appreciated, thanks.

contact_post.php

```
<?php
    /*
    THIS FILE USES PHPMAILER INSTEAD OF THE PHP MAIL() FUNCTION
    */
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    
    require 'PHPMailer.php';
    require 'Exception.php';
    
    /*
    *  CONFIGURE EVERYTHING HERE
    */
    
    // an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
    $fromEmail = 'info@domain.co.uk';
    $fromName = 'Info domain';
    
    // an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
    $sendToEmail = 'info@domain.co.uk';
    $sendToName = 'Info domain';
    
    // subject of the email
    $subject = 'New message from contact form';
    
    // form field names and their translations.
    // array variable name => Text to appear in the email
    $fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message');
    
    // message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
    $okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
    
    // If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
    $errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';
    
    /*
     *  LET'S DO THE SENDING
     */
    
    // if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by error_reporting(0);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
    try
    {
        
        if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');
        $emailTextHtml = "<h1>You have a new message from your contact form</h1><hr>";
        $emailTextHtml .= "<table>";
        
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email
            if (isset($fields[$key])) {
                $emailTextHtml .= "<tr><th>$fields[$key]</th><td>$value</td></tr>";
            }
        }
        $emailTextHtml .= "</table><hr>";
        
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        
        $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
        $mail->addAddress($sendToEmail, $sendToName); // you can add more addresses by simply adding another line with $mail->addAddress();
        $mail->addReplyTo($from);
    
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->msgHTML($emailTextHtml); // this will also create a plain-text version of the HTML email, very handy
        
        if(!$mail->send()) {
            throw new \Exception('I could not send the email.' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
        }
        
        $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        // $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
        $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e->getMessage());
    }
    
    
    // if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
    if ($responseArray['type'] == 'success') {
        // success redirect
    
       //header('Location: /php/form_complete.php');
    }
    else {
        //error redirect
        //header('Location: /php/form_error.php');
    }
```

form on contact.html

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="/contact_post.php" role="form">

    <div class="messages"></div>

    <div class="controls">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_name">First name*</label>
                    <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your first name *" required="required" data-error="First name is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_lastname">Last name*</label>
                    <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your last name *" required="required" data-error="Last name is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_email">Email*</label>
                    <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_need">Please specify your need*</label>
                    <select id="form_need" name="need" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Please specify your need.">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Request quotation">Request quotation</option>
                        <option value="Request order status">Request order status</option>
                        <option value="Request copy of an invoice">Request copy of an invoice</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_message">Message*</label>
                    <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter message here*" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="text-muted">
                    <strong>*</strong> These fields are required.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: You are catching exceptions (so no error will be logged) but are then doing nothing other than setting an array value, so you have no output to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment, you're not doing anything when something goes wrong, so there's nothing to see.

To see what's actually going wrong, output something useful when it does, for example:

```
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = ['type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e->getMessage()];
    var_dump($responseArray, $mail->ErrorInfo);
}
```

One small thing:

```
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        throw new \Exception('I could not send the email.' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
    }
```

There's no need to do this – PHPMailer is already set to throw exceptions, so this should just be:

```
$mail->send();
```

Comment: Thank you. Helped me find another issue which was the $from variable wasn't definied.